# How to extract a sample of pairs in grouping variable

Tags: r

My data looks like this:

```
x  y 
1  1
2  2
3  2
4  4
5  5
6  6
7  6
8  8
9  9 
10  9
11  11
12  12
13  13
14  13
15  14
16  15
17  14
18  16
19  17
20  18
```

y is a grouping variable. I would like to see how well this grouping went.
Because of this I want to extract a sample of n pairs of cases that are grouped together by variable y
and n pairs of cases that are not grouped together by variable y. In order to calculate the number of 
false positives and false negatives (either falsly grouped or not). How do I extract a sample of grouped pairs
and a sample of not-grouped pairs?

I would like the samples to look like this (for n=6) :
Grouped sample:

```
x  y
2  2
3  2
9  9
10  9
15  14
17  14
```

Not-grouped sample:

```
x  y
1  1
2  2
6  8
6  8
11  11
19  17
```

How would I go about this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on what you like to do, partly because I feel there is some context missing as to what you're trying to achieve. I also don't quite understand your expected output (for example, the not-grouped sample contains an entry `6 8` that does not exist in your original data...)

That aside, here is a possible approach.

```
# Maximum number of samples per group
n <- 3;

# Set fixed RNG seed for reproducibility
set.seed(2017);

# Grouped samples
df.grouped <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(split(df, df$y),
    function(x) if (nrow(x) > 1) x[sample(min(n, nrow(x))), ]));
df.grouped;
#       x  y
#2.3    3  2
#2.2    2  2
#6.6    6  6
#6.7    7  6
#9.10  10  9
#9.9    9  9
#13.13 13 13
#13.14 14 13
#14.15 15 14
#14.17 17 14


# Ungrouped samples
df.ungrouped <- df[sample(nrow(df.grouped)), ];
df.ungrouped;
#    x y
#7   7 6
#1   1 1
#9   9 9
#4   4 4
#3   3 2
#2   2 2
#5   5 5
#6   6 6
#10 10 9
#8   8 8
```

Explanation: Split `df` based on `y`, then draw `min(n, nrow(x))` samples from subset `x` containing `>1` rows; `rbind`ing gives the grouped `df.grouped`. We then draw `nrow(df.grouped)` samples from `df` to produce the ungrouped `df.ungrouped`.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "x  y
     1  1
     2  2
     3  2
     4  4
     5  5
     6  6
     7  6
     8  8
     9  9
     10  9
     11  11
     12  12
     13  13
     14  13
     15  14
     16  15
     17  14
     18  16
     19  17
     20  18", header = T)
```